# How to convert an integer to a string in GLib?

Tags: glib

I want to convert an integer value to string in GLib. Is there any macro or function to da that? Or Can i store different data types in the same doubly linked list?

Answer (score 7):

1. `gchar *my_string = g_strdup_printf("%i", my_integer);`
2. Yes, you can store any pointer you want, or even an integer using `GINT_TO_POINTER`, but how will you know what data type to get back out?

Comment: 1.Thanx a lot for ur answer... 
2.I am actually storing an expression in a doubly linked list. So all odd nodes (starting from 0) will be operators and even nodes the operands.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you should use a tree for that, otherwise how will you give different operators different priorities?